# Passing a SECRET KEY as environment variable in gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I have stored a key in the Secret manager of GCP and I'm trying to use that secret in the `cloudbuild.yaml` but every time I have this error:

`ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) argument --set-secrets: Secrets value configuration must match the pattern 'SECRET:VERSION' or 'projects/{PROJECT}/secrets/{SECRET}:{VERSION}' or 'projects/{PROJECT}/secrets/{SECRET}/versions/{VERSION}' where VERSION is a number or the label 'latest' [ 'projects/gcp-project/secrets/SECRETKEY/versions/latest' ]]`

My cloud build file looks like this:

```
steps:
  - id: installing-dependencies
    name: 'python'
    entrypoint: pip
    args: ["install", "-r", "src/requirements.txt", "--user"]

  - id: deploy-function
    name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    args:
    - gcloud
    - functions
    - deploy
    - name_of_my_function
    - --region=us-central1
    - --source=./src
    - --trigger-topic=name_of_my_topic
    - --runtime=python37
    - --set-secrets=[ SECRETKEY = 'projects/gcp-project/secrets/SECRETKEY/versions/latest' ]
    waitFor: [ "installing-dependencies" ]
```

I was reading the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--set-secrets), but I don't have any other clue that could help me.

Comment: to start with - can you check that there is no spaces in the `--set-secrets=...` line?

Comment: Remove the space?

Comment: Yes, I have removed the spaces. In fact, those are the different combinations that I've tried:

**1st try**
`--set-secrets=[SECRETKEY = 'projects/gcp-project/secrets/SECRETKEY/versions/latest']`

**2nd try**
`--set-secrets=[SECRETKEY ='projects/gcp-project/secrets/SECRETKEY/versions/latest']`

**3rd try**
`--set-secrets=[SECRETKEY =projects/gcp-project/secrets/SECRETKEY/versions/latest]`

Comment: I still see spaces in all three examples you provided

Comment: @Pin90 Posted an answer, Is it helpful?

Comment: @Pin90 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @DivyaniYadav, the answer does not work for me, the space in my question was a typo. In my project, I do not have any space. BTW thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by al-dann, there should not be any space in set-secret line  as you can see the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--set-secrets)
Final correction in code :

```
 --set-secrets=[SECRETKEY='projects/gcp-project/secrets/SECRETKEY/versions/latest']
```

For more information, you can refer to the [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68502970/15774176) and [blog](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secret-manager-improve-cloud-run-security-without-changing-the-code-634f60c541e6) where brief information about secret manager has been well explained.